# Is there an Android intent-filter that triggers whenever the user switches to the app?

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova

I'm very new to configuring the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in an Android app, and the app I'm building is using Phonegap with Javascript and HTML, not native code.

I have some actions in my Javascript code that I want to trigger every time the user "opens" the app. What I've discovered is that the concept of "open" has more to it than I first understood. If the user opens the app, and then switches to another app, and then comes back to the first app, the first app has actually still been running in the background, so it's not starting up. I guess it would be more accurate to describe that as "switching" back to the first app.

My issue is that I have some Javascript that runs every single time the user switches to my app, whether opening it for the first time or if it had been running in the background. I didn't have to do any particular configuration to make that happen, it seems to be the default behavior.

However, some actions I need to execute are based on settings in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but they ony execute if the app is being opened for the first time, *not* if the user is switching back to an app currently running in the background. Specifically, I want to execute actions based on whether or not the user opens the app from a link in an email, for which I set up an `<intent-filter>`.

Is there a way I can listen for when the user has launched my app from a link in an email, regardless of whether or not the app is already running in the background?

I think it might be relevant, so here is my `<activity>` tag in my `AndroidManifest.xml` that "listens" for the app being launched via URL:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="xxxxxxx.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="xxxxxxx.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the the `onCreate()` function in my `MainActivity.java` file:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 3000);

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit);
        LinearLayout layout = super.root;
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about phone gap, but in the Android SDK, you have to create class that overrides `Application`, register on the Android Manifest and do whatever you want in the `onCreate()` callback. I think you can do something similar by checking the intent from the Launcher Activity.

Comment: @DiogoBento: Thank you for responding. I've added my current `onCreate()` code to my question. I'm out of my depth with Java programming though. Could you be a little more specific about how I override `Application` to acheive what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. now I'm a little confused. Do you want to get notified only when the user clicks on a link to your app? or every time your app goes to the foreground?

Comment: @DiogoBento: Thanks your continued help. In this instance, I only need to get notified only when the user clicks a link to my app. Now that I'm starting to get a grasp of the terminology, I think I can describe my problem this way: The issue is that I don't get notified when the user clicks a link to my app if the app is already running in the background. I need that notification regardless of whether the app is running in the background or not.

Comment: check this if your activity is defined as `singletop`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29 this is a callback that you can override in the `MainActivity`. and don't forget to call `super.onNewIntent(intent)`

Comment: @DiogoBento: That sounds very promising, although, like I said, my Java-fu is very weak,since I'm a Javascript/HTML guy. Any chance you could throw an example of the code you're talking about into an answer, Which I could then mark as correct?

Comment: @DiogoBento: It's very helpful. I'm still testing a bit, so I'm not totally sure my issue is resolved yet. I will report back here when I've confirmed my sitation with a little more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your Launcher activity:

```
//this method is called every time the Activity is Created or Re-Created
//we check for null to see if the activity was only Created instead of Recreated
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){ 
        myMethod(getIntent());
    }    
}

//This method will be called only when the Activity is already created and receives
//a new Intent
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent it){
    super.onNewIntent(it);
    myMethod(it)
}

private void myMethod(Intent intent){
    if(intent.getAction().equals("put here the WebIntent action string or URL as they call it"){
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. Unfortunately, I'm failing to use it in such a way as to ensure that the WebIntent plugin runs each time, which is my ultimate goal, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18565253/184108).